# Titles of subplots are shown when kind='bar' but not when kind='line'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

When I create subplots like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 10), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=(4, 3), sharex=True, sharey=False)
```

I get a plot like this where the column headers are used as titles of the subplots:

[image]

When I change `kind='bar'` to `kind='line'`, there are only the legends but not the titles plotted.

A workaround would be to use `.get_legend_handles_labels()` like this:

```
for axi in itertools.chain.from_iterable(ax):
    try:
        axi.set_title(axi.get_legend_handles_labels()[1][0], {'size': 16})
    except:
        pass
```

which then gives the proper output:

[image]

Is there a more direct way of achieving this? Why does `plot` behave differently depending on the flag `kind`?

Comment: I would open an issue at the pandas bug tracker for this. Looks like an inconsistency to me.

Comment: @languitar Ok, will wait for a bit to see if someone knows what is going on. Any recommendations about a workaround I could use?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely put up an issue on the [pandas issue page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround:

1. Get the current [development version of `plotting.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/998c801f76256990b98d3f0d2ad885ae27c955a1/pandas/tools/plotting.py). This allows to provide lists to the `titles` argument of `plot`.
2. Use

   ```
   ax = df.plot(kind="line",subplots=True, layout=(4, 3), 
            sharex=True, sharey=False, title=list(df.columns.values))
   ```

   to get the subplot titles.

Of course you could also directly try to change the code to include the setting of the axes titles. The code for the barplot is around line 2006 in the current dev version; and you would need to place it to the `_make_plot()` method of the LinePlot somewhere around line [1757](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/998c801f76256990b98d3f0d2ad885ae27c955a1/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L1758), where a simple `ax.set_title(label)` is sufficient. The problem may then be that pandas will ask you to rebuid it. (Which I haven't tested).

Comment: I think an addition of `ax.set_title(label)` in [line no.1732](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L1732) is sufficient.

Comment: Ok, I copied the entire file and used the `title=...` part and this indeed worked fine, thanks (upvoted). As always, I wait for a while and then accept the answer.